# Routing traffic from OpenVPN clients to OPT1

Tags: pfsense

I'm trying to route traffic from OpenVPN clients to a host connected to my pfSense's OPT1.

- OpenVPN network: `192.168.9.0/24`
- OPT1 network: `10.139.251.104/29`
- OPT1 address: `10.139.251.109`
- Destination host I am trying to connect to: `10.195.111.12/26`

pfSense itself has no problem communicating with `10.195.111.12/26`, but I am at a loss how to route traffic from OpenVPN to it. I thought it would be as easy as adding a `route 10.195.111.0 255.255.255.192` line to my `.ovpn` configuration file, but apparently not.

I'm sorry if this sounds trivial but I'm not a network engineer, just trying to connect to a server so I can use the database on it. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the OpenVPN *clients* that need to have a route to send the packets into the tunnel, the *gateway* needs to have a route to the destination when that isn't the (likely configured) default route.

Also, the other gateways (pfSense, ...) require a route back to the OpenVPN clients unless they can use their default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Which interface is your pfSense router using to connect to 10.139.251.104? It doesn't fall within the range of your Opt1 interface's subnet, so unless there is another interface whose subnet includes this IP in its range OR you have a static route defined, then it will use the default gateway which is usually your WAN interface.

As it's a private address it's likely that the IP is routing through an interface not listed above unless you've created static routes for your pfsense box to use already.

Once you've figured out which interface it's using, create a gateway on that interface in pfsense and define a static route to 10.195.111.12/26 via that gateway. Then modify your OpenVPN SERVER config so that it includes:

```
push "route 10.195.111.0 255.255.255.192"
```

Finally, check your firewall rules to ensure that traffic is allowed to and from the address range in question on both interfaces.